# Table with filtered rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I filter in the table only the lines where the values of "Conversion Time"> "Upper Limit Express Conv"
[image]

Since "Upper Limit Express Express" is a variable that is adjusted with Date slicer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it worked

```
Filter Column =
      VAR Conversion Time = SELECTEDVALUE(Autentique[Conversion Time])
Return
      IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Conversion Time)>[Limite Superior Conversão];"A";"B")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter column to do this:

```
Filter Column =
      VAR UpperLimit = [Upper Limit Express Conv]
RETURN IF([Conversion Time]>UpperLimit,1,0)
```

Once the column is created you can simply use it in the filter pane and filter for either 1 or 0 depending on your needs. Hope this helps.

Edit:

Since the column [Conversion Time] is also not readily available, you can try passing that into a variable:

```
Filter Column =
      VAR UpperLimit = [Upper Limit Express Conv]
      VAR ConvTime = DATEDIFF([Activities.Novo],[Signed_At],DAY)
RETURN IF(ConvTime>UpperLimit,1,0)
```

Comment: [Conversion Time] is a calculated column and therefore does not appear when I try to use if

Comment: Can you share the formula for the column? Ideally it should be available

Comment: I have added an edit to pass the column via a variable. You can check if it works

Comment: Tempo até Conversão = DATEDIFF(Autentique[Activities.Novo];Autentique[signed_at];DAY)

And

Limite Superior Conv Expressa = 
var Q3 = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Autentique[Tempo até Conversão];0,75);ALLSELECTED(Autentique);Autentique[express_deal_document]=1)
var Q1 = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Autentique[Tempo até Conversão];0,25);ALLSELECTED(Autentique);Autentique[express_deal_document]=1)
return 
Q3+1,5*(Q3-Q1)

Comment: Why don't you try the calculation directly in the Filter column, check out my edit

Comment: I tried that way but I couldn't call the column either